# Lower bounds for space with some probability of error

Tags: data-structures, information-theory, lower-bounds

There is an  information theoretic lower bound of $\log_2 {U \choose x}$  for the number of bits to represent a subset of $x$ elements chosen from a universe of size $U$.  We can in principle use this representation (perhaps inefficiently) as a data structure to test if any query is part of this subset.

How can you show a similar information theoretic lower bound if we are happy to have false positives with some probability $p$?

Comment: If you are happy to allow false positives, you are interested in a data structure called Bloom Filters, though sadly I am not familiar with the lower-bound in that framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ["Network applications of Bloom filters: A survey", Broder and Mitzenmacher](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~michaelm/postscripts/im2005b.pdf) show an $x \log_2 (1/p)$ lower bound on the space usage.